# How to make multi-page table with text wrap and auto-width?

Tags: tabularx, supertabular

So, as far as I understand, I can use the `tabularx` package to make auto-width tables with text wrap.

Also, there is `supertabular` which allows me to make tables span across pages.

How do I make a table that:

1. Occupies the whole page horizontally.
2. Spans across multiple pages preserving its header.
3. Automatically selects certain column widths. `tabularx`'s X-style.
4. Wraps text in the columns.

?

Comment: ltxtable.sty (I'm sure this is a duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe `ltablex` package does that: you typeset a `tabularx` environmentas usual, but with `\ caption` command inside the envvironment, and the possibility to use  `\endhead`, `\endfirsthead`, `endfoot`, `\endlastfoot` as in a `longtable` environment.
You have to compile twice.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what is needed. It is much simpler than `ltxtable`, which requires table to be put in a separate file.